# ajax causing to stop further actions on php page

Tags: php, html, ajax, function, reload

I have a page which generates tables by utilizing a for loop. (the syntax works fine in my php file, this is just a copy paste, so disregard syntax errors as this is like a prototype)

```
<form id="formid" name="formName" method="post" action="">                   
<input type="hidden" name="class" value="someclass">
<input type="hidden" name="section" value="somesection">
<select name="school" id="school">          
 $lengthArray = count($Array);                  
for ($k = 0; $k < $lengthArray ; $k++)
  {
    <option> . urldecode($Array[$k]) . </option>;
  }             
</select>       
</form>
```

my Ajax is as the following :

```
$("#school").change(function () {
    // resetValues();

    var data = $("#formid").serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'unexisting.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: data,
        async: false,
        success:function (response) 
                  {      
                    alert("Data Save Successful");
                  }
    });
}
```

Whenever I pick a school from the list for the first time (there are a lot in the list), I am able to call the unexisting.php, But once I do for the first time, the below dropdown lists do not function. I can see all the schools in them and select a value, but doing so does not invoke the unexisting.php file.

Where am I going wrong ? Should I fix things inside onSuccess ?

Comment: can you explain "But once I do for the first time, the below dropdown lists do not function" ..

Comment: @Rishabh Since there are several rows in my page, each contains a dropdown list, which is generated by the for loop in the first section.

Comment: and all dropdowns have the same id 'school' ? ids should not be duplicated.

Comment: yes. exactly. 
I now am generating different IDs. but how can I call each drop down list by its unique ID in jquery ?

Comment: why `<option>` doesn't have `value=''` ?

Comment: Alireza41 , the values are being loaded from the db ? I really am newbie in Ajax, so bear with me. Right now I want to get the ID of the dropdown that I am selecting the value of school from and apply it in my code.

Comment: use same classes, bind change event on the class ... store the current changed select dropdowns ID in a variable and pass the ID to your success function

Comment: @Rishabh as I said above, I am newbie in this. can you kindly guide. Moreover, I  dont want to pas them to the onSuccess, why would I ?

Comment: @tony9099 you forgot to open/close php `<?php ?>`

Comment: @Narek I have mentioned - (the syntax works fine in my php file, this is just a copy paste, so disregard syntax errors as this is like a prototype)

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works

```
<form id="formid" name="formName" method="post" action="">                   
<input type="hidden" name="class" value="someclass">
<input type="hidden" name="section" value="somesection">
<select name="school" class="school" id="school1">          
 <?php $lengthArray = count($Array);                  
for ($k = 0; $k < $lengthArray ; $k++)
  { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo urldecode($Array[$k]) ?>"> 
      <?php echo urldecode($Array[$k]) ?> 
    </option> 
      <?php
  } ?>
</select>       
</form>
```

Ajax part

```
var current_changed_id = '';
$(".school").change(function () {
current_changed_id = $(this).attr('id');

var data = $("#formid").serialize();
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'unexisting.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: ListOnSuccess
});

function ListOnSuccess(xmlindata) 
{

    $('#'+current_changed_id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $('#'+current_changed_id).disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Rishabh, still does not work. btw, i have changed on   success: ListOnSuccess with  success : function(response)   {     
alert("Data Save Successful"); } and edited inside the question.

Comment: can be bit more detailed whats not working ? do u see any errors in web page or in console of the browser ?

Comment: I do not see any errors. Actually after adding the code, when I press on other dropdowns, I get the alert of success (now I have alert on success) but the PHP file is never called.